# how to save the value of radio buttons when another new radio buttons are added

Tags: javascript, html

Here I have a button as the user click it add a question with 2 radioButton yes/no as the user choose one value it disappears if the button is clicked again and new radioButtons are added. I want a solution where the value of the checked radioButton will be visible as checked even if the button is clicked and new radioButtons are added. I have tried to make the id tag variable so that each radioButton have a unique id but it does not make any difference. Any help will be very appreciated.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>Radio Buttons </h1>
    <div id = "demo"> </div>
    <br>
    <button onclick="myFunction()"> add </button>


    <script>
      function myFunction() {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += '<br> agree? '+
        '<br>  <input type="radio" id="x"> yes' + ' <input type="radio" id="y"> No <br>'; 
      }
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Writing to an element‘s innerHTML will destroy all children of that element first, and re-create them afterwards – and therefor you lose any checked state changes made by the user, because you don’t have the same radio buttons any more, but new ones. Use a different method to add new radio buttons, not innerHTML. (If you don’t know any, then please go research first.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`innerHTML` will overwrite! And you'll loose previous `input` states.
**Instead use [Element.insertAdjacentHTML()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML)**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>Radio Buttons </h1>
    <div id = "demo"> </div>
    <br>
    <button onclick="myFunction()"> add </button>


    <script>
      function myFunction() {
        document.getElementById("demo").insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", '<br> agree? '+
        '<br>  <input type="radio" id="x"> yes' + ' <input type="radio" id="y"> No <br>'); 
      }
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can include your functionality into a wrapper which will store the `id` you need, call `myFunction` and if there is a valid `id` stored, `click` it to check it.

```
function myFunctionWrapper() {
    var checked = document.querySelector("#demo > input[type=radio]:checked")
    var checkedID = checked ? checked.id : undefined;
    myFunction();
    if (!!checkedID) {
        document.querySelector("#" + checked.id).click();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h1>Radio Buttons </h1>
<div id = "demo"> </div>
<br>
<button onclick="myFunction()"> add </button>


<script>
var x=0;
var y=0;

function myFunction() {

var html=""; 
for(var i=0;i<x;i++)
{
    if(document.getElementById("radio-"+i).checked)
      html=html+"<input type=radio id=radio-"+i+" name=rad-"+i+" checked> Yes <input type=radio id=radio1-"+i+" name=rad-"+i+"> No <br>";
    else
      html=html+"<input type=radio id=radio-"+i+" name=rad-"+i+"> Yes <input type=radio id=radio1-"+i+" name=rad-"+i+" checked> No <br>";

}

html=html+"<input type=radio id=radio-"+y+" name=rad-"+x+"> Yes <input type=radio id=radio1-"+y+" name=rad-"+x+"> No <br>";

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=html;
x++;
y++; 

}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Tested and working.